# How to detect subjective image quality

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

For an image-upload tool I want to detect the (subjective) quality of an image automatically, resulting in a rating of the quality.

I have the following idea to realize this heuristically:

- Obviously incorporate the resolution into the rating.
- Compress it to JPG (75%), decompress it and compare jpg-size vs. decompressed size to gain a ratio. The blurrier the image is, the higher the ratio.

Obviously my approach would use up a lot of cycles and memory if large images are rated, although this would do in my scenario (fat server, not many uploads), and I could always build in a "short circuit" around the more expensive steps if the image exceeds a certain resolution.

Is there something else I can try, or is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: I removed the Python tag because it didn't seem relevant

Comment: It seems like are measuring the resolution, contrast and sharpness of the image, which is "objective" and very different from "subjective quality". Subjective quality is that which is felt by the viewer and can't possibly be determined programmatically, as even 2 humans wouldn't agree on that.

Comment: That's where machine learning methods come into play. But currently the results are not astonishing and usually require lots of computing power.

Comment: This paper by Zhou Wang, Hamid R. Sheikh and Alan C. Bovik might act as a starting point for those who have a serious need for such a function. https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/publications/icip02.pdf

Comment: This is a deep question and hard to solve. Almost any algorithm for identifying quality fails on simple counter examples (i.e., your approach would assign a high quality rating to an image consisting of nothing but sharply defined random points of noise, since such an image would not compress easily). I have been working on this same problem, and have almost come to the conclusion that such an algorithm can only exist within a narrowly-defined range of images, with other narrowly-defined ranges of images each requiring an algorithm of their own. A valid and general answer would be priceless.

Comment: This article https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-image-quality-assessment-in-python-391a6be52c11 might help

Answer (score 11):

Assesing the image (the same goes for sound or video) quality is not an easy task, and there are numerous publications tackling the problem.

Much depends on the nature of the image - different set of criteria is appropriate for artificially created images (i.e. diagrams) or natural images (i.e. photographs). There are subtle effects that have to be taken into consideration - like color masking, luminance masking, contrast perception. For some images a given compression ratio is perfectly adequate, while for other it will result in significant loss of quality.

Here is a free-access publication giving a brief introduction to the subject of [image quality evaluation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=9BDCF27A1C101763342FB0E13B1BDC61?doi=10.1.1.30.3150).

The method you mentioned - compressing the image and comparing the result with the original is far from perfect. What will be the metric that you plan to use? MSE? MSE per block? For sure it is not too difficult to implement, but the results will be difficult to interpret (consider images with high-frequency components and without them).

And if you want to delve more into the are of image quality assessment there is also a lot of research done by the machine learning community.

Answer (score 6):

You could try looking in the EXIF tags of the image (using something like exiftool), what you get will vary a lot. On my SLR, for example, you even get which of the focus points were active when the image was taken. There may also be something about compression quality.

The other thing to check is the image histogram - watch out for images biased to the left, which suggests under-exposure or lots of saturated pixels.

For image blur you could look at the high frequency components of the Fourier transform, this is probably accessing parameters relating to the JPG compression anyway.

This is a bit of a tricky area because most "rules" you might be able to implement could arguably be broken for artistic effect.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to shoot down the "obviously incorporate resolution" idea. Resolution tells you nothing. I can scale an image by a factor of 2 , quadrupling the number of pixels. This adds no **information** whatsoever, nor does it improve quality.

I am not sure about the "compress to JPG" idea. JPG is a *photo-oriented* algorithm. Not all images are photos. Besides, a blue sky compresses quite well. Uniformly grey even better. Do you think exact cloud types determine the image quality?

Sharpness is a bad idea, for similar reasons. Depth of Field is not trivially related to image quality. Items photographed against a black background will have a lot of pixels with quite low intensity, intentionally. Again, this does not signal underexposure, so the histogram isn't a good quality indicator by itself either.

Answer (score 3):

But what if the photos are "commercial?"  Does the value of the existing technology work if the photos are of every-day objects and purposefully non-artistic?

If I hire hundreds of people to take pictures of park benches I want to quickly know which pictures are of better quality (in-focus, well-lit) and which aren't.  I don't want pictures of kittens, people, sunsets, etc.

Or what if the pictures are supposed to be of items for a catalog?  No models, just garments.  Would image-quality processing help there?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also really interested working out how blurry a photograph is.

What about this:

1. measure the byte size of the image when compressed as JPEG
2. downscale the image to 1/4th
3. upscale it 4x, using some kind of basic interpolation
4. compress that version using JPEG
5. compare the sizes of the two compressed images.

If the size did not go down a lot (past some percentage threshold), then downscaling and upscaling did not lose much information, therefore the original image is the same as something that has been zoomed.

Comment: What is the logic here ? If image is blur , size difference will be more ?

Comment: interesting idea, but what if the image is grainy and has a diffused noise, I've seen lot's of photos like that. the algorithm might see the extra noise as more detail, while the quality is actually worse