# How to automatically detect if image is of high quality?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want an algorithm to detect if an image is of high professional quality or is done with poor contrast, low lighting etc. How do I go about designing such an algorithm.

I feel that it is feasible, since if I press a button in picassa it tries to fix the lighting, contrast and color. Now I have seen that in good pictures if I press the auto-fix buttons the change is not that high as in the bad images. Could this be used as a lead?

Please throw any ideas at me. Also if this has already been done before, and I am doing the wheel invention thing, kindly stop me and point me to previous work.

thanks much,

Comment: Step #1 get some reading on #2 get some more reading on. This is covered in many different text books and college-level courses and likely numerous online resources (and I have seen some related SO questions before).

Comment: Why all the buzzwords? (`SVM`, `Artificial Intelligence`, `machine-learning`)  Unless you are looking for some kind of fancy classification for photographs, there are several measurements and techniques of `image-processing` which can supply simple heuristics for what I think you are trying to achieve.  Follow pst's advice to _read_ first and return with more specific questions;  do read-up on image processing first because even if statistical methods were eventually required for your needs, the attributes the SVM or other devices would be based on concepts from digital imagery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560316/how-to-detect-subjective-image-quality Seems like a start.

Comment: @pst Did college level reading. (Have a couple of degrees in math and cs - practice machine learning for several years). This is not an easy problem and is not covered in 'many different text books'.

Comment: @mjv why all the buzz words, they are not buzzing if you understand them for what they are - which I do. I suspect the solution would involve svm at some point which is why I wanted to attract the attention of that community.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer your comment was the only one of value and it is not a co-incidence that you did not try to talk down to me.

Comment: If you want to test an image for "high professional quality", the first task then is to objectively describe _what that is_. This seems difficult to me, because it is at least partially a matter of taste.

Comment: Is the reason this person is getting horribly downvoted because he's asking a basic question, or is it not specific enough? I personally have no idea how to go about doing what he's asking. I'd love to get an answer as well, given that I haven't gone to school for this, while most of you have, apparently. Only one dude has done him the courtesy of helping him out in any tangible way.

Comment: @RolandSmith I think one way to get around the 'taste' problem is to solve a closely related problem. So I would modify my question like this: I would like to know if the image is captured with good fidelity, instead of being over/under exposed, with good lighting/contrast and color.

Comment: user1521607: welcome to StackOverflow. I'm sorry if you get the idea that I and other are trying to "talk down to you"; while you may find the SO community relatively impatient with bad questions, you'll find that in general it is very respectful of novices and experts alike.  The fact is that there is a disconnect between the apparently trivial task at hand and the _keywords_ used, hence either the need for you to lay out more precisely which kind of effect you are seeking or to acknowledge that a simple approach like that propose by Kirk Strauser fits the bill.

Comment: @TankorSmash thanks for your humanity man (or women). I was loosing hope on SO. And this is not a basic question, atleast not for me.

Comment: @TankorSmash I concur. It's an interesting question and I'm not sure why people are downvoting it (and voting to close it?!?).

Answer (score 3):

You are making this way too hard. I handled this in production code by generating a histogram of the image, throwing away outliers (1 black pixel doesn't mean that the whole image has lots of black; 1 white pixel doesn't imply a bright image), then seeing if the resulting distribution covered a sufficient range of brightnesses.

In stats terms, you could also see if the histogram approximates a Gaussian distribution with a satisfactorily large standard deviation. If the whole image is medium gray with a tiny stddev, then you have a low contrast image - by definition. If the mean is approximately medium-gray but the stddev covers brightness levels from say 20% to 80%, then you have a decent contrast.

But note that neither of these approaches require anything remotely resembling machine learning.

Comment: @Kirk thanks for the comment. That is the first thing I wanted to attempt. Could you share some accuracy numbers if you have them.

Comment: @Kirk When you say 'making this way too hard' you are not seeing it from a ML engineer's perspective. Throwing in an SVM is a function call for me which I have been doing for years and understand what/how/why etc. So this whole 'stay off machine learning' cause its hard and complicated is from perspective of say a firm ware engineer. I would faint before debugging assembly code, but it is a day in the life of a firmware engineer. Hope my point is clear.

Comment: @user1521607 I apologize, but I don't have access to the numbers anymore. To get started in the right direction, look at the [ImageMagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), particularly the '-auto-level' and '-normalize' commands. Apply normalization to a bunch of images and compare their before-and-after statistics. You can write a learning algorithm to help you find your cutoff points. :-)

Comment: @user1521607 And by "making this way too hard", I mean "using tools that aren't efficient solutions to the problem at hand". I love working with AI stuff and I'm sure you're miles ahead of me. It's just that sometimes there are much lower-level ways to solve a problem. You wouldn't build a Bayesian network to add single-digit numbers - although you certainly could! So I'm not saying that "SVM is too hard a complicated to use for any problem." I'm saying that it's unnecessarily complicated for this one particular problem. :-)

Comment: @KirkStrauser thanks, If I make headway in this line, I will post back some numbers to this thread. (and if I needed to get 'fancy' or if basic worked)

Comment: @user1521607 Cool! Please do.

Answer (score 2):

There are several open source programs that do the kind of image correction you are looking for as indications of a low-quality image. [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) (see [enhancing photos](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-imaging-photos.html) from the documentation) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (see contrast stretch, normalize, adaptive sharpen, auto level from the [examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/examples.php)) come to mind.

Studying their code would be a good start, because an obvious way to detect a low-quality image is to put the image through one of the aforementioned enhancement algorithms and look for differences between the original and processed image.