# How to detect the zoom factor of an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I read the related question on this topic here: [How to detect subjective image quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560316/how-to-detect-subjective-image-quality)

I would like to detect whether the uploaded image by the user could be zoomed in at high % (say, 500%) and still be or good image quality. I understand that "good image quality" is subjective, but for my purpose I would say it means "whether the image is pixelated?". I'm trying to find ways of how to do that?

- Should I calculate the size of the uploaded image? Higher the size, more zoomed in it can be?
- Should I calculate the total pixel count of the image?
- Should I read the metatags of the uploaded image?
- Combination of multiple things?

Are there solutions/libraries out there that determine the [bad pixelation](http://umagowrishankar.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/spot_pixelated_new.gif) of an image?

Comment: Blur != pixellation. Are you concerned about [blurry images](http://www.flickr.com/photos/funtik/1805895416/lightbox/), or pixellated ones?

Comment: *ANY* upsizing of an image is going to make it blurrier, the original image quality makes no difference. You should base your decision on whether your zoom will make the image larger or smaller.

Comment: I'm no expert, but a fun coding way could be to implement a blob coloring algorithm on the image - this would let you find definitive lines in the image.  Then you can zoom into the line and repeat blob coloring on that section until you notice a lot more blobs around the line.  There's probably a better way to do it though

Comment: @MattBall, there are many ways of resizing an image. Most of them will make it blurrier, but only one will make it pixellated.

Comment: @MattBall I'm concerned about pixellated images rather than blurry ones. I've updated the question

Comment: @MarkRansom the zoom will make the image larger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the horizontal and vertical pixel count.

As long as the image has more pixels than you're displaying, you can zoom.  Once you have more display pixels than image pixels, you have to interpolate the pixels.  The higher the interpolation, the blurrier the picture.

Say you have a 4000 x 3000 pixel picture, and you're displaying 640 x 480 pixels.

You can zoom up to 625% horizontally (4000 / 640) and 625% vertically (3000 / 480).  The smaller zoom number would be 625%.  Rounding to an even zoom number, this picture could be zoomed up to 600% without pixelation.

Now, you could zoom even higher than 600%, if you're willing to interpolate the pixels.  How high can you zoom?  That would depend on what you consider acceptable interpolation.

My guess would be 25% higher.  For this example picture, you could go to 800% before the picture got too blurry.

If you want to be on the safe side, keep it below the calculated zoom size.  If not, go as high as you wish and let the user determine how high is too high.

Comment: That helps a lot.Though, I'm not displaying the image. User will upload an image and the app will decide whether the image is pass/fail. An admin will set some sort of threshold that determines whether the image is pass/fail. That threshold could be in pixels. i.e. 640 x 480 in your example

Comment: Good suggestion, but this wouldn't catch an image that a user has already blown up would it?  Say a user had a source image of 64x64 and then blew it up to 64kx64k before uploading to the app.  It'd look terrible, but if you go only by image dimensions, you're SOL.

Comment: @Anon: True.  If you'd like, you can share with us how you would analyze the pixels of a picture and detect an extreme enlargement as opposed to a picture with only a few colors.

Comment: I'm no expert - but maybe this answer on SO might help -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942365/detecting-a-pixelated-image-in-python